# Select many rows on low-cardinality column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select, cardinality

I have a table in SQLite with very many rows, and I frequently need to select all rows based on a binary column with about even split (say male/female for example). There are no other conditions in the query that must be satisfied. I've understood that it's not good to index in this case, but is there any other way to make this fast? Something like sorting the table? Other than making two separate tables I guess.

EDIT: If there isn't in SQLite would it be possible in another SQL-based RDBMS?

Comment: Uh... indexing is "like sorting the table".  Either ignore the previous advise or provide a good reference to why an index is a bad idea in this case.  Also, does the table contents change much, or is it mostly static?  I can't imagine that forcing the system to rescan the entire table each query is better than having an less-than-ideal index.  Two tables sounds like a very annoying alternative, especially if you do have other queries.  I don't see how having to do UNIONS and jumping through other hoops would be better than an index.

Comment: Deciding between SQLite and another SQL-based RDBMS should probably be based on [many other factors](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), not just whether or not to index one table.  Especially since SQLite is an embedded database designed for very specific needs of a local, server-less database, whereas most other SQL RDBMS will be servers and fullfil other needs.

Comment: Sure, and based on those factors I've opted for SQLite (server-less is a great benefit, largely read-only db, few users). The size is huge though, but my impression was that the queries would be just as fast with SQLite as with some other system (maybe faster since no server layer and too big db to keep in memory). Anyways, I'm anyways missing some features in SQLite, e.g. materialized views, so switching is an option if there are other advantages.

Comment: I also found chitchat about having such "low cardinality" index as worse than no index for various reasons about many index lookups being less efficient.  Perhaps that's true for *lookup* of a foreign key or secondary search (e.g. after other indexes are used for primary sort).  But if such an index is used for a simple selection, a good optimizer could partition a table into blocks of rows for efficient processing rather than querying the index for every single row.  Honestly, I'm not prepared to argue one way or the other for sqlite, but I think its bad to just dismiss/ignore.  Test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've understood that it's not good to index in this case

There are always pros and cons to consider in such matters, so what's really important is the weight you give to each of them.  In other words,  it is often advisable to conduct one's own due diligence rather than relying on someone else's rules of thumb.

In my timings of an SQLite db with 1 million rows with a binary column split evenly between 0s and 1s, `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE binary = 0;` was sped up significantly with an index.  Here are the u+s times:

```
   without an index: 0.06 secs
   with an index:    0.04 secs
```

For 10m rows, the difference was even more pronounced.